# How to search start and end with square bracket with multiple line

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

Text have

```
[{hello=(1+2-0), 
hello2 = 1}]
```

But are in two or three multiple lines when start with [ and end with ] are in different line

How to extract like grep for this multiple line pattern?

Comment: maybe you could parse the file before matching `tr -d \\n < text | awk -F '}]' '{ for (a=1; a<NF; a++) print $a "}]" }'` it puts everything on one line.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way to do multiline grep-like matches is to install `pcregrep` from the `universe` repository.

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
Text have

[{hello=(1+2-0), 
hello2 = 1}]
But are in two or three multiple lines when start with [ and end with ] are in different line

How to extract like grep for this multiple line pattern?
```

then

```
$ pcregrep -M '(?s)\[.*?\]' file
[{hello=(1+2-0), 
hello2 = 1}]
But are in two or three multiple lines when start with [ and end with ] are in different line
```

Comment: (?s) gets me into trouble, if I have 'three' and try to match #2 it matches 1,2?

Comment: my regex `'(?s)\[\{hello=\(.*?\),\s\nhello5.*?\}\]'`

Comment: fixed it `'(?s)\[\{hello=\([0-9+-]+\),\s+.hello5.*?\}\]'`

Comment: is there a way to make `.*?` not to eat up the beginning?

Comment: @bac0n `(?s)` effectively makes `.` match the newline (ordinarily, it matches any single character excluding newline). You can omit it and use `\n` explicitly (as you did) - imho the advantage of `(?s)` is that you don't need to know exactly where the newlines are i.e. you can just use a non-greedy `.*?` between the `\[` and `\]`. Not sure what you mean about not eating up the beginning...?

Comment: if i understand this right `[\{hello=` will match #1 and i think .*? will match everything between #1 and #5 because `\),\s+.hello5` belongs/glued to its own match so pcre has no choice but to match everything in between? at  the end you could just do .* but i cant find same for the beginning